# Can't install linux on Dell XPS 15z

Tags: linux, installation

I'm trying to install a linux destro on my Dell XPS 15z laptop but have had no success. In this lets say I'm using Ubuntu 15. The cd works, I can see the live versions of Ubuntu, and Ubuntu can see the hard drive, but when I try to install. It can not detect my hard drive and therefor I can't select the hard drive I like to install on. I only have 1 hard driver partitioned into 4 partitions. I currently have Windows 7 on one of those partitions. I have tried to install Unbuntu, Debian and Fedora, and none of them can see my hard drive, when I try to install?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have explained yourself clearly but still it might help if you take a pic from your phone , a screenshot, paste the screenshot  to imgur, and  include a link to it

Comment: In addition, it would be interesting to know if the hard drive is connected using an mSATA SSD Module. Generally the mSATA and the HDD are set in a RAID config. I've had the same issue on my Dell (not an XPS though). If I remember correctly, I've had to load a specific driver in order for the operating system to recognize it.

Comment: I'm not sure what picture to post since there is no error messages? Just a blank on the hard drive detection screen.
I don't know what kind of hard drive connection its using, how can I find out? I believe its just using a sata connection, but not sure if its configured for raid?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments I found that I had to remove raid on installation sudo apt-get remove dmraid and in my bios set the hard drive to ahci Once I did those things it worked.